# How to mark org agenda item as completed on particular day?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Sometimes I fall behind in my org-agenda maintenance and have to go back a few days to mark completed tasks. In 90% of cases, I want to mark the task as completed on the day it was due, but `org-agenda-todo` always uses the current day and time.

What is the easiest way to mark agenda items as completed on the day currently being viewed in the agenda window?

**Update:** I attempted to adapt the answer to the linked question; ignoring the ugliness of my code, the date seems to be obtained, but `org-agenda-todo` ignores `org-current-effective-time`:

```
(defun org-agenda-todo-view-date (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (cl-letf* ((org-read-date-prefer-future nil)
             (my-current-time (org-read-date nil t (mapconcat 'number-to-string (append (last (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute org-starting-day)) (butlast (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute org-starting-day))) "-")))
             ((symbol-function #'org-current-effective-time)
              #'(lambda () my-current-time)))
    (org-agenda-todo arg)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make org prompt for a timestamp, when changing state of a TODO?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/how-to-make-org-prompt-for-a-timestamp-when-changing-state-of-a-todo)

Comment: Similar, but not duplicate. Edited to clarify. Linked question wishes to be prompted for a completion date, but I want the current agenda view day to be used. It should be fully automated, no manual input required beyond pressing `t` to complete the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to [another](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/how-to-make-org-prompt-for-a-timestamp-when-changing-state-of-a-todo) question where the goal was to prompt for the date.  Here you just want to use the date under the cursor.  We can basically use the same answer, but we get the date in a different way.  Instead of prompting with `org-read-date`, we use `org-get-cursor-date`.  With this the `CLOSED` property and any logbook entries will be made on whatever date in the agenda you happen to be on when you call `org-agenda-todo-view-date`.

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun org-agenda-todo-view-date (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((my-current-time (org-get-cursor-date)))
    (cl-letf* (((symbol-function #'org-current-effective-time)
                (lambda () my-current-time))
               ((symbol-function #'org-today)
                (lambda () (time-to-days (org-current-effective-time)))))
      (let ((current-prefix-arg arg))
        (call-interactively 'org-agenda-todo)))))
```

Note that the function responsible for updating schedules, `org-auto-repeat-maybe`, uses `org-today` to get the date instead of `org-current-effective-time` (which `org-today` apparently does not call) so we modify it as well to match.

Comment: Wow, that is much simpler way to get the date. =) One problem remains. As is, it moves the due date to the day after today, rather than the day after the day in the agenda view. Any idea how to rectify this?

Comment: The scheduling function seems to get the date from `org-today` instead of `org-current-effective-time`.  We'll have to modify that function as well.

Comment: Yes! That seems to work as intended. Thank you very much for your help. Learned a bit about org internals to boot.